# IRepository and Unit Of Work vs Eager Loading

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, eager-loading

I know having a `Unit Of Work` is having an abstraction on top of an abstraction (`DbContext`) and surely that is an anti-pattern, or at least is not necessary.

I have the following problem:

I have a generic `IRepository` like so:

```
public interface IGenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
        Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
        string includeProperties = "");

    TEntity GetByID(object id);

    void Insert(TEntity entity);

    void Delete(object id);

    void Delete(TEntity entityToDelete);

    void Update(TEntity entityToUpdate);
}
```

and this is the implementation of this interface:

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> : IGenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    internal GymHelperContext context;
    internal DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;

    public GenericRepository(GymHelperContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
        Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
        string includeProperties = "")
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> query = dbSet;

        if (filter != null)
        {
            query = query.Where(filter);
        }

        foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split
            (new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        {
            query = query.Include(includeProperty);
        }

        if (orderBy != null)
        {
            return orderBy(query).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            return query.ToList();
        }
    }

    public virtual TEntity GetByID(object id)
    {
        return dbSet.Find(id);
    }

    public virtual void Insert(TEntity entity)
    {
        dbSet.Add(entity);
    }

    public virtual void Delete(object id)
    {
        TEntity entityToDelete = dbSet.Find(id);
        Delete(entityToDelete);
    }

    public virtual void Delete(TEntity entityToDelete)
    {
        if (context.Entry(entityToDelete).State == EntityState.Detached)
        {
            dbSet.Attach(entityToDelete);
        }
        dbSet.Remove(entityToDelete);
    }

    public virtual void Update(TEntity entityToUpdate)
    {
        dbSet.Attach(entityToUpdate);
        context.Entry(entityToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
}
```

I have a proyect called Facade that instantiates a Mapper and a UnitOfWork, like so:

```
public class MuscleFacade
    {
        private readonly UnitOfWork _unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork();
        private readonly MuscleMapping _muscleMapping = new MuscleMapping();

        public MuscleFacade()
        {

        }

        public IEnumerable<MuscleViewModel> GetAllMuscles()
        {
            var source = _unitOfWork.MuscleRepository
                .Get()
                .ToList();

            var result = source.Select(x => _muscleMapping.MuscleToModel(x));

            return result;
        }

        public GymViewModel GetGymViewModel()
        {
            GymViewModel gymViewModel = new GymViewModel
            {
                ListOfMuscles = GetAllMuscles().ToList()
            };

            return gymViewModel;
        }

    }
```

The `MuscleFacade` class it's what I inject on my controller with Autofac, I inject an `IMuscleFacade` in its constructor.

Now the thing is, my `MuscleTypeViewModel` have a list of `MuscleViewModel` these models are mapped with their Domain classes counterparts, and in this particular case a `MuscleType` have many `Muscle` (Eg: Arm have bicep, tricep, etc) so I put navigational properties on each of them, like so:

```
public class MuscleType : IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    public string MuscleTypeName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Muscle> Muscles { get; set; }
}

public class Muscle : IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    public string MuscleName { get; set; }

    public int MuscleTypeId { get; set; }

    public MuscleType MuscleType { get; set; }
}
```

Now let's look at `GetAllMuscles` method in the Facade again:

```
public IEnumerable<MuscleViewModel> GetAllMuscles()
{
    var source = _unitOfWork.MuscleRepository
        .Get()
        .ToList();

    var result = source.Select(x => _muscleMapping.MuscleToModel(x));

    return result;
}
```

What if I want to Eager-Load MuscleType, how can I change the Get() in order to receive and `Expression` of `Func` instead of a `string`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a helper class that contains your include definitions:

```
abstract class IncludeDefinition<TEntity>
{
    public abstract IQueryable<TEntity> Include(IQueryable<TEntity> entities);
}

class IncludeDefinition<TEntity, TProperty> : IncludeDefinition<TEntity>
{
    public IncludeDefinition(Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>> includeEx)
    {
        _includeEx = includeEx;
    }

    private readonly Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>> _includeEx;

    public override IQueryable<TEntity> Include(IQueryable<TEntity> entities)
    {
        return entities.Include(_includeEx);
    }
}
```

Then use the `IncludeDefinition` in your `Get` method

```
public IEnumerable<Muscle> Get(params IncludeDefinition<Muscle>[] includes)
{
    IQueryable<Muscle> muscles = ...;
    foreach (var item in includes)
    {
        muscles = item.Include(muscles);
    }
    return muscles.ToList();
}
```

And call the method

```
_unitOfWork.MuscleRepository
    .Get(new IncludeDefinition<Muscle, MuscleType>(m => m.MuscleType));

// Include as many as you wish
_unitOfWork.MuscleRepository
    .Get(new IncludeDefinition<Muscle, MuscleType>(m => m.MuscleType),
         new IncludeDefinition<Muscle, SomeOtherRelatedEntity>(m => m.SomeOtherProperty));
```

**Edit** here comes some way to *"just include"* instead of writing complicated syntax.

Create a new interface `IQueryRepository` that supports `Get` without explicit includes and `Include`, derive `IGenericRepository` from this interface:

```
public interface IQueryRepository<TEntity>
     where TEntity : class
{
    IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
        Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null);

    IQueryRepository<TEntity> Include<TProperty>(Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>> referenceExpression);
}

public interface IGenericRepository<TEntity> : IQueryRepository<TEntity>
     where TEntity : class
{
    IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
        Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
        params IncludeDefinition<TEntity>[] include);

    // other methods like GetByID, Add, Update...
}
```

Update the `GenericRepository` definition - it uses the approach with `IncludeDefinition` that I initially described and it returns a `GenericQueryRepositoryHelper` when `Include` is called.

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> : IGenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    internal DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;


    public IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null, Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null)
    {
        return Get(filter, orderBy, new IncludeDefinition<TEntity>[0]);
    }

    public IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null, Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null, params IncludeDefinition<TEntity>[] includes)
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> query = dbSet;

        foreach (var item in includes)
        {
            query = item.Include(query);
        }

        if (filter != null)
        {
            query = query.Where(filter);
        }

        if (orderBy != null)
        {
            return orderBy(query).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            return query.ToList();
        }
    }

    public IQueryRepository<TEntity> Include<TProperty>(Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>> referenceExpression)
    {
        return new GenericQueryRepositoryHelper<TEntity>(this, new IncludeDefinition<TEntity, TProperty>(referenceExpression));
    }

    // other methods like GetByID, Add, Update...
}
```

Implement the `GenericQueryRepositoryHelper` to store includes and apply them when `Get` is called

```
public class GenericQueryRepositoryHelper<TEntity> : IQueryRepository<TEntity>
    where TEntity : class
{
    private readonly IList<IncludeDefinition<TEntity>> _includeDefinitions;
    private readonly IGenericRepository<TEntity> _repository;

    internal GenericQueryRepositoryHelper(IGenericRepository<TEntity> repository, IncludeDefinition<TEntity> includeDefinition)
    {
        _repository = repository;
        _includeDefinitions = new List<IncludeDefinition<TEntity>> { includeDefinition };
    }

    public IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null, Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null)
    {
        return _repository.Get(filter, orderBy, _includeDefinitions.ToArray());
    }

    public IQueryRepository<TEntity> Include<TProperty>(Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>> referenceExpression)
    {
        _includeDefinitions.Add(new IncludeDefinition<TEntity, TProperty>(referenceExpression));
        return this;
    }
}
```

Happy querying with includes:

```
var repo = new GenericRepository<Muscle>(...);
repo.Include(x => x.MuscleType)
    .Include(x => x.MuscleType.Muscles)
    .Get(x => x.MuscleName == "Test", x => x.OrderBy(m => m.MuscleName));
```

Comment: This is a very good solution, I came up with another one, would you like to view it?, Im gonna put it as "Edit" on my post.

Comment: @Nickso in your edit you mention how you dislike the look of your solution... can you give an example of how you would expect a *good* solution to look like? I have to admit, that the introduction of the `nameof` operator mitigated the need for an expression based include mechanism. Before `nameof`, the string version was bad for code maintenance.

Comment: I agree. Magic strings is not good. Not only that it is weird to have magic strings or const for includes. People just .Include. at least that is why I see.

Comment: @Nickso see my edit - maybe that's what you mean with *"People just .Include"* ;)