# How to do a search in two or more tables using Join with Entity framework Lambda and Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework

How would I do to search two or more tables.

In the system I'm doing, I have the `Boat`, `TypeOfBoat`, and `ClassBoat` tables.

My mapping is as follows:

```
HasRequired(c => c.ClassBoat )
            .WithMany(c => c.Boat)
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.ClassBoatId);

HasRequired(c => c.TypeOfBoat)
            .WithMany(c => c.Boat)
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.TypeOfBoatId);
```

I made a generic repository for searching

```
    public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Search(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return Dbset.Where(predicate);
    }
```

And I use a generic Interface repository to do specific searches for boats, here are some examples below:

```
    public IEnumerable<Boat> GetByActive()
    {
        return Search(c => c.Active && !c.excluded);          
    }

    public Boat GetByName(string name)
    {
       return Search(c => c.Name== name).FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

And if I want to fetch the `TypeOfBoat` and the `ClassBoat`, which are different tables, but which are related with the `Boat` table, how would I do?

My idea is to show this data in a table

Here's a SS how my Database is.

[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QT4qG.png)

Comment: example of expected result?

Comment: I recently answered a somewhat related question. Depending on what you are actually looking for, this might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52934296/5265292

Comment: @ingvar Let's suppose I want to know which class and Type of boat, a particular boat belongs to

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean including related records for boat?

Try if this query gives you the expected result

```
public Boat GetByName(string name)
{
   var boat = DbContext.Boat
             .Include(boat => boat.ClassBoat)
             .Include(boat => boat.TypeOfBoat)
             .FirstOrDefault(boat => boat.Name == name);

   return boat;
}
```

If you want to use generic repository and then extend query you should return `IQueryable<T>` instead of `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: Yes, Let's suppose I want to know which class and Type of boat, which particular boat belongs to

Comment: @Jhensen I think, that the code for query i given above will give the expected result then.